# fread takes two columns in one

Tags: r, data.table, fread

`fread` captures only 2 columns instead of 3, is there any missing parameter to take into account?

input:

```
fread("3-2    0.123 0.572
       4-1    0.833 0.271
       3-8    0.249 0.289
       3-4    0.368 0.367
       8-12   0.127 0.964
       10-11  0.722 0.559
       11-12  0.930 0.158
       12-13  0.541 0.358
       13-14  0.615 0.273
       14-15  0.906 0.149")
```

result:

```
              V1    V2
 1: 3-2    0.123 0.572
 2: 4-1    0.833 0.271
 3: 3-8    0.249 0.289
 4: 3-4    0.368 0.367
 5: 8-12   0.127 0.964
 6: 10-11  0.722 0.559
 7: 11-12  0.930 0.158
 8: 12-13  0.541 0.358
 9: 13-14  0.615 0.273
10: 14-15  0.906 0.149
```

Comment: On my computer, your code resulted in 3 columns. What version of `data.table` you are using?

Comment: @www version `1.10.4`

Comment: I am using version `1.11.8`.

Comment: @www thank you, I'll update my version.